# When doing a POST from an iframe to be recharged in it does not save the Cookie

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cookies

Good.
I am trying to develop a login from a web so that then that login leads to an iframe with the user already logged in.

I have been doing tests with POSTMAN and everything works correctly but at the time of logging in from my HTML file (tested on a local server) to load it in the iframe it seems that something is not going as it should and I get the login As incorrect.

I have entered the network and the data is being sent correctly, the necessary data are the web path, login, user and a token.

What strikes me is that in the cookie comes out at the end as * DISMISS * so the problem may be there.

My code is this:

```
<form action="http://web.com/login_check" method="POST" target="my_frame">
  <input type="hidden" name="_crsf_token" value="o1lPdSPkIO6a-c_3icovq7A45gA18bNJjUTdREMsFsA" />
  <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="http://web.com/" />
  <input type="hidden" name="_username" value="ju@email.com" />
  <input type="hidden" name="_password" value="1234" />
  <input type="hidden" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
<input type="submit" />
```

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" name="my_frame" src="http://web.com/">
```

Regards

Comment: So is the iframe content from a different origin than the main page? In that case, it is most likely just your browser settings regarding third-party cookies ...

Comment: Actually i start loading the iframe making a POST. Anyway if i load the iframe in the same origin (http://theweb.com/) and i try to do a login who is located in http://theweb.com/login_check i catch the same error... Who i don't obtain the cookie response. The web is designed on symfony but i have access to the code... Can i modify something to make it works? I'm doing an Ionic project and i wanna do a native login and then send that parameters to a POST who will be loaded on an iframe (strating with the user logged). Sorry for my english and thanks

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you remove the `sandbox` attribute from the iframe completely?

Comment: Yes.. The same response in network and cookies section if i disable sandbox: In the iframe https://i.gyazo.com/5fb362de1bddd74ebdddc4d33367c10f.png Making the login through the web form https://i.gyazo.com/c1b4fdf49fcdb28a551e697247aac609.png